# Inner Class method access to parent method's variable

Tags: java

Why can't method r access variable c? I know it can't access the variable but I'm trying to understand why it doesn't.

```
public class A {
  public void m() {
    class B implements I {
      public void r() {
        . . .
      }
    }
    final int c;
    . . .
  }
}
```

Comment: Does that actually compile? I wasn't aware you could nest inner classes in methods.

Comment: Pointing me to documented information would be fine too.

Comment: There are two additional types of inner classes. You can declare an inner class within the body of a method. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html  || One of my homework assignments for class covered this question, this should be a valid use of inner classes. I'm just trying to figure out how this inner class can't access the variable c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `c` is a local variable and is not in scope by the time the local class `B` is declared.

If you declared it before the declaration of the class, and properly initialized it, you could use it

```
class A {
    public void m() {
        final int c = 42;

        class B implements I {
            public void r() {
                System.out.println(c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this answers the question with your statement. Rather than trying to fix the code I was looking for a reason why this didn't work. When compiling this the editor throws, "cannot find symbol - variable c". So the scope makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your code:

1. The variable `c` is final but is not being assigned a value. You must set it to something when you declare it.
2. If you want to access `c` from method `r()` then you have to declare it first, that is, before declaring the method `r()`.

The easiest way to fix this is by moving variable `c` to the `A` class instead of declaring it in class `B`.